# Cross-compilation: running `make install` on the build (non-target) system

Tags: make, cross-compilation

I understand the basic concept of using a cross compiler to compile code on one architecture and then copying the executable to another architecture to run it. But I can't figure out the last step of the typical `./configure; make; make install` sequence in the context of cross compiling.

For example, I want to cross-compile libusb for an ARM device using my Ubuntu PC. I downloaded the libusb source code, ran configure and make:

```
> ./configure --disable-udev --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
> make
```

At this point, I have a bunch of libusb compiled binaries for the ARM architecture. Ideally, I want to copy those binaries over to the ARM device and run `make install` so that I don't have to manually copy them into their destination directories. But that would mean I'd have to copy over the entire build environment from the Ubuntu computer, which seems like a waste of time and disk space. Or I could gather just the binaries and the appropriate Makefiles and copy them over, but that seems clunky.

Is there a more elegant way to take advantage of `make install` on the destination architecture?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, at least for Autotools-based build systems, as used here (and probably some others); these support a [`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html) variable which can be used to install somewhere other than `/`.

```
mkdir destdir
make DESTDIR="${PWD}/destdir" install
```

This will give you the target binaries (and accompanying files) in `destdir`; you can then copy that to the target device's `/`.

Comment: So I would never run make on the destination computer. Just copy the directory of binaries over to the destination computer and do one big copy to `/`?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

OK, As @Stephen Kitt mentioned you can pass `DESTDIR` to `make install`. Here I will provide one more possible option you can try,

- **Run `configure` script with `--prefix=/your/custom/install/dir/path`**

You can pass `--prefix` along with your custom path to configure script. So that whenever you run `make install` it will install to the `prefix` directory.

Example:

```
./configure --disable-udev --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --prefix=/your/custom/path
```

- **Run `make install` with `DESTDIR`**

`make install` supports `DESTDIR` variable which will be prepended to installed target file.

Example:

```
make DESTDIR=`pwd`/DESTDIR install
```

Comment: When you specify `--prefix`, you need to use the target directory that you want to use *on the target system*; you can't use `--prefix` to install somewhere handy that's not the real installation directory. (Well, you can in some cases, but you can't rely on that.)

Comment: @StephenKitt  Well, It completely depends on the build rules but most of the standard packages will have the support. At least it is recommended to use standard Directory Variables. For instance, `bindir` will have `/prefix/bin/*`

Comment: I agree `--prefix` is widely supported; what I'm saying is it's not intended for the use you're putting it to here (unless I'm misunderstanding your intentions). `DESTDIR` is *designed* for the kinds of scenarios the OP is interested in.

Comment: @StephenKitt : Nod :)

Comment: The distinction between target and staging prefix is crucial when cross-compiling. For example libcrypto from OpenSSL uses prefix to access certificates and engine data at runtime. You can see that the actual prefix paths are compiled into the binary.