# make file trying to figure out postgresql source code DESTDIR mean

Tags: make, postgresql

[make append and separate by white space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709739/make-append-and-separate-by-white-space)
https://superuser.com/questions/360178/what-does-make-install-do
Trying to understand the following make command.

```
installincludes:
    $(INSTALL) -d '$(DESTDIR)$(includedir_server)/'
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(addprefix $(srcdir)/, $(RELATIVE_INCLUDES)) '$(DESTDIR)$(includedir_server)/'
```

rg is rigrep regex command, like grep.
To understand this, I first begin with `includedir_server`.

```
 pg_config | rg server
```

return

```
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/postgresql/15/server
```

In folder `/src` (postgresql source code) do

```
cat Makefile.global.in | rg --line-number 'includedir_server'
```

return

```
170:includedir_server = $(pkgincludedir)/server
248:override CPPFLAGS := -I$(includedir_server) -I$(includedir_internal) $(CPPFLAGS)
```

To understand `$(INSTALL) -d '$(DESTDIR)$(includedir_server)/'` now I feel like the follow logic is true.

```
$(includedir_server)  ==  $(pkgincludedir)/server  == /usr/include/postgresql/15/server
```

But if the above logic is true, then $(includedir_server) is already a full path. Then what is `$(DESTDIR)`?
also  `$(INSTALL) -d` what does this part do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html) is intended for use when you want to install somewhere other than the real target path, for example if you’re preparing a package or if you’re installing into a chroot from outside. You won’t find it defined in the build, it’s specified externally when necessary (see [Cross-compilation: running `make install` on the build (non-target) system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328845/86440)).

`$(INSTALL) -d` creates the directory given as argument.