# Why pass "--prefix=/usr" to configure scripts in Linux from Scratch builds?

Tags: configure, lfs

Why in Linux from scratch they are passing `--prefix=/usr` to configure scripts?
For example here is the `glibc` configure script

```
../configure                             \
      --prefix=/usr                      \
      --host=$LFS_TGT                    \
      --build=$(../scripts/config.guess) \
      --enable-kernel=3.2                \
      --with-headers=$LFS/usr/include    \
      libc_cv_slibdir=/usr/lib
```

Shouldnt it be `--prefix=$LFS/usr` so it gets installed there and not in the host system's `/usr`?

Answer (score 1):

The `--prefix` argument to `configure` determines where the compiled program should *expect* to be installed. The ultimate goal is to have a system where `/usr` contains the programs being built, so they are configured with the expectation that they will run from `/usr`.

Installation itself doesn’t have to happen in `/usr` as viewed from the host system. In LFS, build and installation is done in a chroot anyway; in other scenarios, the installation itself is done with a prefix (*e.g.* [using `DESTDIR`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709827/86440)).